# Search filter pagination issue using php and mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Here when i am searching key in search filter for shorting row from database based on search filter using pagination its showing correct but when i am clicking for second page its leaving the search filter and catching second query and which is only for pagination,

Here is my pagination code

```
 <ul class="pagination">
                  <?php
                    for($i=1;$i<=$total_page;$i++)
                      echo"<li class='".($page_id == $i? 'active' : '')."'><a href='index.php?page=".$i."'>$i</a></li>";
                  ?>

              </ul>
```

and here is code when clicking for second page its leaving  search session and going to again in normal pagination part

```
<?php
                 $total_num_page=1;
                if(isset($_GET['page']))
                {
                $page_id=$_GET['page'];
                }
                else
                {
                   $page_id=1;
                }
              if(isset($_POST['submitSearch']) || $_SESSION['search'])
                {

                    if($_POST['submitSearch']){
                        $_SESSION['search']=$_POST['search'];  
                    }

                    $all_post_query= "select * from files where recieved_by like '%". $_SESSION["search"]. "%' or processed_by like  '%".$_SESSION["search"]."%' or   purpose like  '%".$_SESSION["search"]."%' or file_name like  '%".$_SESSION["search"]."%' order by date desc";
                    $all_post_run=mysqli_query($con,$all_post_query);
                    $all_post=mysqli_num_rows( $all_post_run);
                    $total_page=ceil($all_post/$total_num_page);
                    $page_start_from=($page_id-1)*$total_num_page;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                   $all_post_query="select * from files order by date desc";
                   $all_post_run=mysqli_query($con,$all_post_query);
                   $all_post=mysqli_num_rows($all_post_run);
                   $total_page=ceil($all_post/$total_num_page);
                   $page_start_from=($page_id-1)*$total_num_page;
                  }?>
```

and this is code where fetching the data to table from database

```
   <?php
                    $p_query="select * from files order by date desc limit $page_start_from, $total_num_page";
                          $p_run=mysqli_query($con,$p_query);
                            if(mysqli_num_rows($p_run)){
                             while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($p_run))
                             {
                                $c_id=$row['id'];
                                $file=$row['file_name'];
                                $purpose=$row['purpose'];
                                $recieve=$row['recieved_by'];
                                $processed=$row['processed_by'];
                                $address=$row['address'];
                                $contact=$row['contact_no'];
                                $date=$row['date'];


                            ?>
                                            <tr>

                                                <td><a  href="post.php?post_id=<?php echo $c_id?>"><?php echo $c_id;?></a></td>
                                                <td><a href="post.php?post_id=<?php echo $c_id?>"><?php echo $file;?></a></td>
                                                <td><a href="post.php?post_id=<?php echo $c_id?>"><?php echo $purpose;?></a></td>
                                                <td><a href="post.php?post_id=<?php echo $c_id?>"><?php echo $recieve;?></a></td>
                                                <td><a href="post.php?post_id=<?php echo $c_id?>"><?php echo $processed;?></a></td>
                                                <td><a href="post.php?post_id=<?php echo $c_id?>"><?php echo $address;?></a></td>
                                                <td><a href="post.php?post_id=<?php echo $c_id?>"><?php echo $contact;?></a></td>
                                                <td><a href="post.php?post_id=<?php echo $c_id?>"><?php echo $date;?></a></td>
?>
```

So help me please and I know code is vulnerable to SQL injection that I will prevent this after completing .

Comment: Use GET to search instead of POST. Then simply pass the search word to each page in your pagination. Btw, _"I will prevent this after completing"_ - Famous last words. Suggestion: Never knowingly write insecure code. You will forget to sort some stuff out afterwords, and/or you will introduce new bugs when refactoring. Best to just to it right from the start.

Comment: Also, when working with sessions, make sure you have `session_start()` in your code, before any output is made.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code:

First of all, when you select the data to display the table, you don't take the search param into consideration, so you will never display records filtered by search.

Also, you don't need to do "SELECT * FROM.." in order to get the count of all records, doing  "SELECT COUNT(id) as count  FROM.." is much more efficient

If you are storing the search param in the $_SESSION, make sure you have  session_start() on top of your PHP scripts

Comment: after inserting session_start() on the top and search param to display filter its start working

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson - It's not count(*) vs count(id),  i was speaking about SELECT * FROM to retrieve all the data and get count though mysqli_num_rows - as in the code snippet from OP

Comment: but session is not destroying where i have to put  session destroy() to destroy the search filter session after clicking another search key or another   link

Comment: @Raj -  if you want to "Clear" the session variable just unset it - unset($_SESSION['search'])

Comment: can you explain me @mike_t sir , how session_start work and after which line i have to use unset($_SESSION['search']) , help me again sir

Comment: when i am again searching or clicking at another link and coming back at that page its showing that in session filter value , i am so much  new in this field  and i am embarrassed to ask  this , sorry sir , but help me @mike_t

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158583/discussion-between-raj-and-mike-t).

Comment: @Raj i sent you solution in chat.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson no worries :)